# Redirecting url in web.config with a rewrite rule

Tags: regex, web-config, redirect

I'm writing a rewrite rule in my web.config. I currently have traffic going to an AMP page, the url looks like this:

```
mydomain.com/post-title/amp/
```

I want it redirected to the normal page here:

```
mydomain.com/post-title/
```

I need to strip out the "`amp/`" from the end of the url in all cases.

I've taken a stab and just wondered if this is the correct way of handling this? I'm not sure the regex is correct, plus do I need to include the domain?

```
<rule name="Rewrite AMP url">
      <match url="/([_0-9a-z-]+)/amp/" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/" />
    </rule>
```

Is this correct?

Comment: `amp/` is always going to be at the end or can something else can come after it?

Comment: I think it should be `\/([_0-9a-z-\/]+?)\/amp(.*)` and then `{R:1}{R:2}`

Comment: The regex is almost correct, it will match `/some1-thing2/amp/` in  `/some1-thing2/amp/more/here/to/follow`. Add a `$` at the end. If the slash is optional, add a `?` after it. So, it will look like `url="/([_0-9a-z-]+)/amp/?$"`.